# nginx + SSL certificate not valid on Android

Tags: android, ssl, nginx

I have problem with my ssl certificate is not valid only on android devices, here is my nginx domain conf:

```
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name teatrclub.pl www.teatrclub.pl;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen   8080;
  listen 443 ssl;

  ssl    on;
  ssl_certificate    /etc/ssl/teatrclub.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key    /etc/ssl/teatrclub.key;

  server_name teatrclub.pl www.teatrclub.pl;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
  }
}
```

Here is also my domain analyze:

https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=teatrclub.pl

I'm green on nginx configuration and ssl, so maybe some one can give me some hint?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you did not install all intermediate certificates. You can see this where it says "Extra Download" by two certificates under the "Certification Paths" section of your ssllabs report.

Most desktop browsers will automatically have common intermediate certificates so it'll handle this for you, but some mobile operating systems might not have all of these by default.

You need to chain your certificates together using something like https://certificatechain.io/ and then update your nginx configuration to point to the new chained certificate.

Comment: I spent two days trying to understand why my Android app did not work with my HTTPS server. And the reason was exactly as you wrote. Thank you very much!